# Can you import eclipse C++ code formatting files into kdevelop?

Tags: c++, eclipse, kdevelop

I have an eclipse code formatting file that is exported from the Export button in the Project Properties->Formatter->Edit window.

Is it possible to import this into kdevelop somehow?  Kdevelop appears to use the `indent` command; perhaps this could be an intermediary that would bridge the two.

Comment: Not possible at the moment I'm afraid. Found a work-around?

Comment: Just doing it manually.